# can't format memory stick, get errors

Tags: ram, format

I tried to format my memory stick,it says operation failed, but I get the following errors:

```
Error creating partition table: 
helper exited with exit code 1: 
cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found.
```

I used the disk utility to format it. And I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
What can I do? Please assist me in this. Can I format it in fat32 like you would normally be able to do in Windows?

Comment: try to format in gparted.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gparted`, I had same problem and `gparted` have helped me.
For install run `sudo apt-get install gparted`